# Analog Reference (AREF) pin on Arduino MKR1000 not working?

Tags: analogreference

Has anyone successfully used the AREF pin on [MKR1000](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/MKR1000)?

I'm trying to use an EXTERNAL voltage reference (I need 1.5V instead of the default 5V) with:

```
analogReference(EXTERNAL)
```

But when I compile I receive the following error message:

> MKR_001:161: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'eAnalogReference {aka _eAnalogReference}' [-fpermissive]

In the documentation (for analogReference) I found the following:

> DEFAULT: the default analog reference of 5 volts (on 5V Arduino boards) or 3.3 volts (on 3.3V Arduino boards)
>   INTERNAL: an built-in reference, equal to 1.1 volts on the ATmega168 or ATmega328 and 2.56 volts on the ATmega8 (not available on the Arduino Mega)
>   INTERNAL1V1: a built-in 1.1V reference (Arduino Mega only)
>   INTERNAL2V56: a built-in 2.56V reference (Arduino Mega only)
>   EXTERNAL: the voltage applied to the AREF pin (0 to 5V only) is used as the reference.

Thanks,
Corrado

Comment: What doesn't work. What have you tried and in what way did it fail?

Comment: Please edit your question with this information and any more that you have. Also, try to make your question more specific.

Comment: Voted to reopen, you've edited the question and I think it's a very good question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler error

```
MKR_001:161: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'eAnalogReference {aka _eAnalogReference}' [-fpermissive]
```

Is actually really simple once you understand what it means.

```
analogReference(EXTERNAL);
```

The function `analogReference` takes an integer as a parameter, but you are passing it `EXTERNAL` which is an enumeration.  Its probably an enumeration that uses integers for its values, but to the compiler there is a difference.

If you want to disable the warning then you can use the `-fpermissive` flag on the compile command line, this is not a good idea because it invalidates the "type-safeness" of the language for the whole program.  Instead it is better to address them on a case by case basis and just cast EXTERNAL to an int.

```
analogReference((int)EXTERNAL);
```

Comment: Interesting, it's somewhat a bug of the 'analogReference()' function to expect an int (could be much more than just one of the enum values)?

Comment: Its not a bug, its a feature :)
I think it stems from the tightening of implicit type conversion within the gcc compiler.  I knew it straight away, because I see it so often at work, dragging some legacy code into this century.   Someone could raise it as a fault and have it changed, but its not going to be a priority.

Comment: Well, yeah, if you keep it too long out there, people will go use integers to choose the reference. And then correcting it may break those peoples code again. But your answer is a very good one.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogreference/) suggests that for SAMD boards (MKR1000 is based on Zero) a different enumeration should be used where each value is prefixed with `AR_` so for example you should use `analogReference(AR_EXTERNAL);`.